# return of a null value using generics in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a pop() method in Java by using Generics, my method is the following:

```
public T pop(){
        T elem;
        if (list!=null){
            elem=list.get(this.getSize()-1);
            list.remove(this.getSize()-1);
            return elem;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

If I put some n values on the stack, and want to print their values I am doing the following:

```
System.out.println(stack.pop());
```

The problem that I have is when I want to pop a n+1 value instead of printing a null value it returns an error which is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Is there someway that when the stack is empty to print a null value? because I am returning a generic type T, and as far as I know Java is not able to tell which object will it be in advance.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry I just put it

Comment: Why would `list` be `null`? Just check if it’s empty.

Comment: For future reference, check out https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public T pop() {
    T elem;
    if (list!=null || list.isEmpty()) {
        elem=list.get(this.getSize()-1);
        list.remove(this.getSize()-1);
        return elem;
    } else return null;
}
```

Check if the list is empty, not just null. `isEmpty()` might need to change depending on the structure being used.

Comment: On my view. it should be && operator in the `if (list!=null || list.isEmpty()) {`

Answer (score 1):

If your list is empty, for sure you'll get ArrayIndexOutofBounds since you try to get element at index -1. You can use isEmpty to check if list is empty.

BTW, remove will return the removed element from the list, you don't have to do a get beforehand.

And for your last statement, java generics is something happened at compilation time. You're not allowed to put an array to a List of String. But they are no difference at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the list is empty.

The exception is thrown because when the list is empty (size = 0), you try to get the (size - 1) element (index: -1). In java, arrays are indexed beggining from 0, so the ArrayOutOfBoundsException comes around.

```
public T pop(){
    T elem;
    if (list != null || list.isEmpty()){
        elem = list.get(this.getSize()-1);
        list.remove(this.getSize() - 1);
        return elem;
    }
    else return null;
}
```